# React useEffect run conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect, react-effects

How do I prevent my React component from fetching images every time the component is rendered and to fetch them from the store instead? I don't want to get rate limited by doing the API call over and over again, but the problem with `useEffect` is that it seems to be unaware of the variables being set "outside" of the effect. It seems to completely ignore `!images.length` and when I log the value for `images.length` it is always `0` :(

**Images.tsx**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const images = useSelector(selectedImages);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!images.length) {
    dispatch(fetchImages());
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: you can maintain a flag in `localStorage` to check this

Comment: `Images` should be in your useEffect’s dependency array. Second arg in your useEffect should be `[images]`

Comment: @johnnypeter wont that would be re-render every time `images`'s length will change ?

Comment: Yes that will trigger everytime the length changes. To avoid fetching an already fetched image, you can maintain and internal cache to book keep what is already downloaded and skip them.

Answer (score 1):

It is always logging `0` is because you didn't put anything inside dependency array of `useEffect` so that whenever React re-render your component, it looks inside the `useEffect` and see nothing inside the dep array, so it just skip running that `useEffect`.

When you use `useEffect`, you should declare dependencies in the array of `useEffect` that are used inside `useEffect`

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const images = useSelector(selectedImages);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!images.length) {
    dispatch(fetchImages());
  }
}, [images]); // Our deps
```

So, let's say:

1. First, by default it will run the `useEffect` and do all the logics inside that effect. If the images array is empty, calling the API to get images.
2. Second, `images` array is not empty anymore, and the 2nd `images` is different from 1st `images` array which is empty, so it still run to the `useEffect`. But it won't fetch images anymore because you have `if condition` there.

Answer (score 0):

With React hook `useMemo` you will only call the API whenever you need it

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usememo-hook

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo